# How to ask for a strategy or pointers to a solution?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I asked a question about how to tackle a certain problem.

The question was asking if exists a "tool or something else" to tackle that certain problem. Now, I candidly and completely forgot the "no asking for tools" rule, so the question was closed.

How can one ask a question about "how do I tackle this kind of problem"?
(I'm aware that a possible answer is "SO is not a place for this kind of questions": it's why I'm asking)

Even Meta has plenty of discussions about gray areas about specific wording issues in questions, determining if a question is ok, too broad, or off topic.
It seems really easy to mess the wording up (especially for non native speakers).

**Edit**: as George Stocker suggested, I'm linking the question that left me wondering about this kind of issues.

[How do I ensure shared assemblies are ABI/API compatible in .NET when their version changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57783541/how-do-i-ensure-shared-assemblies-are-abi-api-compatible-in-net-when-their-vers)

It seemed to me the question had a topic, and possibly it got closed because of the original wording, which was naive at best (I specifically asked for suggestions about a tool, how stupid).

In other words: I think that a question like that as a perimeter that is not too broad, and that "asking for a tool" in a case like that, is more about not knowing how to tackle the problem than about anything else. Does editing a question removing the "is there any tool" part makes it a better question? I don't know...

Still, I really don't want to transform this question into a flame war about my original question. Thanks to every one that bothered to comment!

Comment: In short, you can’t.

Comment: @DanBron I feared so...

Comment: Can't you simply ask "How to do X", describing X with enough details and context so valuable answers can be provided?

Comment: @A.Chiesa Is this the question? It's well scoped, answerable, and it's a problem programmers face: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57783541/net-assembly-compatibility-analysis

Comment: @yivi That is usually closed as "Too broad". I don't know how to solve the problem X and I'm open to suggestions. I found this is a recipe for failure on SO.

Comment: SO users get a bit, erm, open-minded when they vote on a question that has no solution.  A personally think an "it is not possible" answer is the most useful one there can ever be, cuts off a goose-chase that can occupy a programmer for months.  But lordy do such answers get downvoted.  SO visitors only like happy answers, nothing you can do about it.

Comment: "How to" doesn't equate to "too broad". You need to provide enough so the question is adequately scoped, but how-to questions are welcome if they are good and interesting.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Yep. I didn't want to mention it because I didn't want to be "ranty". I just want to understand if I should ask and how should I do it.

Comment: @A.Chiesa At the risk of invoking the meta effect, it'll help your case here. Your specific question that this meta question is based on is a good question; and it doesn't match what you're asking in this question.

Comment: Just for the record, my comments were only meant to address this meta-question. I have not seen question on main linked in comments.